# Building Unreal Engine 4: OS_X

Tags: xcode, macos, unreal-engine4

After downloaded from github,
run the `GenerateProjectFiles.command` file,
it says

> Setting up Unreal Engine 4 project files...
>
> GenerateProjectFiles ERROR: It looks like youre missing some files that are required in order to generate projects.  Please check that youve downloaded and unpacked the engine source code, binaries, content and third-party dependencies before running this script.
>   ~/UDK_4.0/UnrealEngine
>   logout

But I already have `Xcode 5.1`
and officially they have no reference about third-party dependencies.
any ideas to try?

Comment: More details are required.  Find out what dependencies it's looking for.

Comment: following the .command, I found  "if [ ! -d ../../../Binaries/DotNET ]; then \n echo~~ exit"

Comment: You should probably ask on the unreal engine forums.  I looked around for a while and couldn't even confirm if the UDK supported Mac (or vice versa).

Comment: at GDC, they announced that they would support mac, and also in their official website. thanks for your effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter the github site again there should be a Getting started page / Readme. You need to follow the links to download the two required files and extract them into the folder where you have the source / command file.

Comment: I did, no work. warning says can't find gcc compiler, though I have recent gcc compiler. thank you for answer